# For PyCharm/WebStorm my IDE's local server is not detecting other directories

Tags: configuration, pycharm, webstorm

When I select a html file to open "in browser" in Webstorm it works and it opens under the localhost. The issue I'm having is that this webstorm internal server is not detecting any of the other paths in my project root like images and javascript files.

I should note that this feature has worked before on other projects I started from scratch using "new project." The difference with this project is that I opened a directory as a project.

Comment: please can you be more specific? What do you mean by 'not detecting paths'?

Comment: So when I open an html file on the IDE localserver, the page itself opens but the static files like pictures, css files and javascript don't load, because the internal localserver isn't serving them.

Comment: what do references to your static files in HTML look like? Do you use URLs relative to web server root - starting with slash? Please see comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14350 for some hints

Comment: Yes I do use relative paths. If I run a external test server like http-server from node everything works!

Comment: you need to either modify your hosts file as suggested in youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14350 or use a differen server to host your files then

Answer (score 0):

The built-in webserver serves files from `http://localhost:<built-in server port>/<project root>.` Forward slashes in URLs tell the browser to resolve them relative to the web server root (`localhost:63342` in your case), causing 404 errors.

If you like to change the default web path on built-in web server, you have to re-configure the server by editing your system hosts file accordingly - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8988#comment=27-577559.